# Facing timeout issue in Azure Durable function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient, connection-timeout, azure-durable-functions

I'm using Azure Durable function to perform some batch processing operations. Something in the lines of Read, Process, Notify
There was a limit of 10, to the number of times these operations were expected to be executed

- Read, Process, Notify
- Read, Process, Notify
- Read, Process, Notify
- ..
- ~10 times
- ..
- Read, Process, Notify

However if I increase this to a bigger number, say 100
I get this error message:
"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

The function handler that is responsible for the connection being used up is as given below:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HandleAsync(string uri, string body, int retryCount)
{
    Ensure.That(uri, nameof(uri)).IsNotNull();
    Ensure.That(uri, nameof(uri)).IsNotEmptyOrWhiteSpace();
    Ensure.That(body, nameof(body)).IsNotNull();
    Ensure.That(body, nameof(body)).IsNotEmptyOrWhiteSpace();
    var iteration = 0;
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    do
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var (key, value) = _tokenProvider.GetAuthenticationHeader(_appSetting.PayloadConfig).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(key, value);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-version","1.0");

        var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
        msg.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
        msg.Content = new StringContent(body);
        msg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        response = await client.SendAsync(msg);
        iteration++;
    } while (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode && iteration < retryCount);
    await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync();
    return response;
}
```

How can I solve this to avoid this starvation?

What I tried was editing this pool's max number of connections

```
private HttpClient Client
        {
            get
            {
                var socketsHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
                {
                    PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                    PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    MaxConnectionsPerServer = 100
                };
                
                var _httpClient = new HttpClient(socketsHandler);
                return _httpClient;
            }
        }
```

And using the Client

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HandleAsync(string uri, string body, int retryCount)
        {
            Ensure.That(uri, nameof(uri)).IsNotNull();
            Ensure.That(uri, nameof(uri)).IsNotEmptyOrWhiteSpace();
            Ensure.That(body, nameof(body)).IsNotNull();
            Ensure.That(body, nameof(body)).IsNotEmptyOrWhiteSpace();
            var iteration = 0;
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            do
            {
                var (key, value) = _tokenProvider.GetAuthenticationHeader(_appSetting.PayloadConfig).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(key, value);
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-version","1.0");

                var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
                msg.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
                msg.Content = new StringContent(body);
                msg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                response = await Client.SendAsync(msg);
                iteration++;
            } while (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode && iteration < retryCount);
            await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync();
            return response;
        }
```

However, i'm still facing the same issue
Can anyone guide me here

Comment: For first approach what happens if move `var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(); and code to add default headers` outside of do/while loop. The second approach you are creating a new instance of HttpClient which is not correct. You can create the static instance of HttpClient and re-use it.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that as well @user1672994

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you don't create an HttpClient every time with `var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();`.
Move it out of the loop.
And don't use DefaultRequestHeaders, just set those on the request instead.

Comment: Yeah, I tried moving out of the loop as a first step initially that didn't work as well. Apologies for not mentioning in my post

Comment: Is that function being called from an activity function in Durable Functions?

Comment: Yes @juunas this is called from a preceding activity